# Checking for doubled entries in value separated by commas?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a value like this one: "300, 400, 500, 300" check each number separated with comma and if it is doubled delete it. So the value will look like this : "300, 400, 500".

I could do it in PHP script but I just wonder if it is possible using MySQL.

Comment: In MySQL?  Why would you save a list of comma separated values as one field in a table?  If possible, you should create a new table to hold these, with one value per row.

Comment: Possible, but it would be easier and safer to do it with a php script

Comment: Comma is this `,` and Coma is the thing that people go into when they are not quite dead.

Comment: Well I will only say that I'm working with magento product attribute tables :p

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table with unique index, insert values ignoring duplicate errors, select all records from the temp table, delete the table.

Comment: Can you provide some example how to get each number form this string 100, 300, 500, 500 check if it's doubled and if it is delete it? With MySQL of course.

Answer (score 0):

Quick play, but to get the unique values for each row you could use something like this

```
SELECT Id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT aWord ORDER BY aWord ASC)
FROM (SomeTable.Id, SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(SomeColumn, ','), ' ', aCnt), ',', -1) AS aWord
FROM SomeTable
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 + 1 AS aCnt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
WHERE (LENGTH(SomeColumn) + 1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeColumn, ',', ''))) >= aCnt) Sub2
GROUP BY ID
```

This relies on having a table called integers with a single column called i with 10 rows with the values 0 to 9. It copes with up to ~1000 words but can easily be altered to cope with more

Probably easiest to use an INSERT / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to use this to make the values unique.